EXCEL: Combine multiple cell string into a single cell using Macro VBA
I would like to combine multiple vertical cell in excell assuming from A1:A9 as shown below:
FROM:

    {'BAKWLC001': '10.144.250.240'}
    {'BEWLC002': '10.250.32.249'}
    {'CTALRwlc01': '10.52.188.100'}
    {'CTARXwlc01': '10.20.40.100'}
    {'CTB1wlc01': '10.65.224.20'}
    {'CTBCwlc01': '10.65.194.10'}
    {'CTBGKwlc01': '10.61.248.100'}
    {'CTBIRwlc01': '10.51.200.100'}
    {'CTC0wlc01-new': '10.61.205.100'}

INTO cell A10 as shown below. Which includes Enclosing everything with an Open/Close parenthesis and separating each item with a comma and space. Additionally, The last item shown above should dynamically have the Closing Parenthesis (Assuming there are not just 9 items as shown above. And let us say it has 10, 20, 500 items etc. the last item will have the closing parenthesis).
TO:

    [{'BAKWLC001': '10.144.250.240'}, {'BEWLC002': '10.250.32.249'}, {'CTALRwlc01': '10.52.188.100'}, {'CTARXwlc01': '10.20.40.100'}, {'CTB1wlc01': '10.65.224.20'}, {'CTBCwlc01': '10.65.194.10'}, {'CTBGKwlc01': '10.61.248.100'}, {'CTBIRwlc01': '10.51.200.100'}, {'CTC0wlc01-new': '10.61.205.100'}]

I have Tried using this VBA code:
    Range("A10") = Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A9")), vbLf)

But it only combines all the cells BUT with no parentheses, comma in between, and specially the flexibility of having an enclose parenthesis on whatever item is in the end of the combined cell.

Are you on Excel-2010?

Try Range("A10") = "[" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A9")), ",") & "]"

Iam using Excel for Microsoft 365

Try , comma instead of line feed vbLf. And add square bracket beginning and end of string after join.
Sub JoinText()
    Range("A10") = "[" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A9")), ",") & "]"
End Sub

And TEXTJOIN() function for latest versions of Microsoft Excel.
="["&TEXTJOIN(",",1,A1:A9)&"]"


Edit: To ignore blank cells use Application.TextJoin().

Sub JoinText()
    'Range("A10") = "[" & Join(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A9")), ",") & "]"
    Range("B1") = "[" & Application.TextJoin(",", 1, Range("A1:A500")) & "]"
End Sub


Thanks! Lastly, How can i ignore cells that are blank in the range i have selected? Since i was planning the range to be dynamic. Let us say, Assuming only values A1:A9 have cell values but the range i selected was A1:A12 with cell A10 to A12 as blank?
When i try this, Iam getting multiple comma at the end (one for each blank cell) . How  can i ignore/bypass this blank cell on the range that i have selected and should have no comma at the end of the last item.

@Flow-Pleyah Is there any reason to choose VBA? TEXTJOIN() if simpler solution and can easily ignore blanks. See edited answer please.

Hi @Harun24hr I plan on putting it on a button and be flexible on where the code output would be shown on different scenario if needed (incl. during presentation. i think it is cool :) when executed properly)

@Flow-Pleyah So, please try my edited codes and let me know your feedback.

Great! code is good as expected! Thank a lot!
